# count for the same table twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

[image]

I want to calculate the number of transaction per month and add another column for overall count per month

The result should be like the following

[image]

I have trying the following code:

```
select  aa.date , aa.department , count(aa.trans_id) "COUNT PER DEPARTMENT"  
, ( select count(trans_id) from table bb where aa.date = bb.date groub by date ) overallcount
from table aa
group by aa.date , aa.department
```

this codes not works takes long time i think something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aggregation and window functions:

```
select date, department,
       count(*) as department_cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by date) as month_cnt
from t
group by date, department;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this-

```
select  aa.date , 
aa.department,
count(aa.trans_id) "COUNT PER DEPARTMENT",
max(bb.overall) overall
from table aa
inner join (
    select date,
    count(trans_id) overall
    from table
    group by date
)bb ON aa.date = bb.date
group by aa.date , aa.department
```

Comment: @Nawaf . . . This is much more complicated than necessary -- and probably slower too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `analytical function` with `distinct` keyword as following:

```
Select distinct date, department,
       Count(1) over (partition by date, department) as count_per_department,
       Count(1) over (partition by date) as overallcount
  From aa;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: In addition to this answer, you need to group by month while counting. Thus, format your date column to char YYYY-MM : TO_CHAR(x.created_date, 'YYYY-MM') instead of using date directly.

Comment: I am sure that dates are truncated to month so i dont think that it is required and group by is not at all required here.

Comment: Select distinct TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM'), department,
       Count(1) over (partition by TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM'), department) as count_per_department,
       Count(1) over (partition by TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM')) as overallcount
  From aa;

Comment: you are right group by is not needed. I mean group by logically.

Comment: I have used inner join with sub-query and it works fine. thank you.